# Package part debugging is not supported when starting SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, business-intelligence, execute-sql-task

This very strange issue. When I press the start button to execute the SSIS project it shows "Package part debugging is not supported" and nothing else. I create a control flow with the data flow task and execute SQL task. I have a simple use case to count rows using variable and store package names and the number of rows in a table on the SQL server. When I open error list it shows

**Error saving PackagePart1.dtsxp: Control flow package part need to contain exactly one executable.

C:\Users\pcp\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Transformations\Transformations\PackagePart1.dtsxp**

[image: Here is the screenshot of the error I am recieving].

Comment: What happens when you right click on the package in the solution explorer and press Execute?

Comment: there is nothing in the SSIS package. When I right-click the package it says to create new package. Sorry, I am new to SSIS I think i didn't create an SSIS package instead I somehow created a package part and deleted the actual package file.

Comment: Oh yes now I see in your screenshot it’s a package part. Just keep experimenting-you’ll work it out!

Comment: TBH I've never used package parts in any SSIS project.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the Debug to Release mode in Visual studio, build and Retry.It worked for me.